# XInput multi pointer changes all cursor state when one changes

Tags: mouse, cursor, xinput, multipointerx

I am working on a setup where I use multiple input devices/cursors to control a webpage. It works fine with reassigning input devices via xinput. There is one problem: When one cursor e.g. hovers on something and becomes a hover cursor, all other cursors also change their appearance.

Is there any way to change this so that each cursors appearance is not influenced by the others?

I have tried working around this by creating a custom cursor theme with only one cursor but that turned out more complicated than expected.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If it's multiple windows of the webpage on separate monitors, then consider setting up X11 multiseat. Otherwise, you could try hiding the Ubuntu cursors, and using Javascript to draw them by moving some `fixed`-positioned `img`s around

Comment: Thanks for you reply :) It is a rather specific setup: the website which is controlled by the cursors contains several iframes which are not same origin, so it might be hard to determine the cursors position!

Comment: This does not seem to be properly supported: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1916

Comment: I was afraid this might be the case. Not using wayland but this seems to be a problem that is not easily fixed.